# TypeScript: return inner class does not work

Tags: typescript

The return in the query method does not work. The console.log(result) shows me the right value. 
The console.log() in the getFirstColumnName() should get the result from the query.

What is wrong?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "spacerowa44",
  database: "m3pilot"
});

export class mySQL{
    connect(){
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("database connected...");
        });
    }

    private getFirstColumnName(table) : any{
        var sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '"+table+"' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1;";
        var result = this.query(sql);
        console.log();
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("1");
            console.log(this.query(sql) );
            return "conditionId";//result[0].COLUMN_NAME;
        },200);
    }

    private query(sql) : any{
        con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `getFirstColumnName` method does not have a return. `query` method does not have a return either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)